# How to read Mac's shell env variable in Swift

Tags: macos, shell

I try to read a password saved in `.zshrc` file as env variable of Mac in Swift code. I tried things like this, but it only show the environment variables related to Xcode.

`ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["myPassword"]`

So how should I read the Mac's env variables in Swift code?

Comment: Your `.zshrc` variables are only readable by your process if you actually run it from a `zsh` shell instance. They will not be available to a "normal" GUI app (unless you start it manually from a `zsh` shell…). So, do you have a terminal or GUI app? How do you start it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. The context there is a UI test case written in Swift, and I want to pass a few password in the test case, but don't want to expose them in code, which is not safe. So I think maybe I could fetch them from the env variable of my Mac machine.

Comment: Store them in a file instead and read the file when testing or try to pass them as arguments or env variables to your test target.

Comment: Yeah, store them in a file could be a way. But pass as args or env variables I think it is same as write them in code, all exposed. I'm thinking about store those password in CI variables, and each time to fetch them from CI server and pass them into the code with fastlane command or something else, still not sure yet.

Comment: Another solution is to add a keychain entry that your app can read. That may involve setting the keychain entry's access permission to "Allow all applications to access this item", so not necessarily better than having it in a file. On a build server like GitLab, you inject it via an environment variable and read it with `ProcessInfo`; it's what we're doing in some cases.

Comment: @DarkDust, our project use GitLab too, I would have a try on this one, thanks.